# How to VBA wait for windows save dialogbox and sendkeys

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2007, sap-gui

I'm creating a macro file that download and save extracted data from SAP old version 7.20 , when the save dialogbox is appear , the windows dialogbox is not detected since my client SAP version is old 7.20. now my resolution on this is the sendkeys but the problem is some of the data is containing large amount that getting unreliable time to send the keys.

How to wait for the save dialogbox and when appear sendkeys.

```
Sub test()

waitTime (10000)
Call SendKeys("{Enter}", True)

End Sub

Function waitTime(ByVal miliseconds As Double)

    Application.Wait (Now() + miliseconds / 24 / 60 / 60 / 1000)

End Function
```

Comment: You could create a vbs script which does that at least I did that in the past with my SAPGUI scripts when the native windows dialog box appeared. But with [7.30 PL 8](https://blogs.sap.com/2014/03/26/new-scripting-option-in-sap-gui-for-windows-730-pl-8/) this is not longer neccessary.

Comment: can you help me how did you do that in your past?

Comment: I assume you have automation code for the SAPGUI, please post that and point out after which call the windows dialog box (usually Save As) appears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume you have some SAPGUI automation code like that

```
 ' This is the last line where you trigger some action within SAPGUI
 .findById("wnd[1]/usr/....     

 ' Let's assume this line triggers the download and with it the Windows dialog box 
 .findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[0]").press
```

Then you have to add the call of the vba script just before the line where the windows dialog boy is triggered, i.e.

```
 ' This is the last line where you trigger some action within SAPGUI
 .findById("wnd[1]/usr/....  

 dim SaveAs as string
 dim xlFile as string
 SaveAs ="Full Path to SaveAs.Vbs"
 xlFile = "Full Path to the xls file"

 Shell "wscript " & SaveAs & xlFile & " Save as"    

 ' Let's assume this line triggers the download and therefore the WIndows dialog box
 .findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[0]").press
```

The SaveAs.vbs script could look like that

```
' WScript.Echo WScript.Arguments.Count
if Wscript.Arguments.count > 0 then 

    ' This first section deletes the file if it already exists, to avoid a prompt to overwrite.
    set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    if fs.fileExists(WScript.arguments(0)) then
      Set myfile = fs.GetFile(WScript.arguments(0)) 
      myfile.Delete
    end if

    'this loop runs until the Save As window finally appears
    set Wshell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    Do 
      ' Argument 1 must be the  excat caption of the Save As dialogbox:
      bWindowFound = Wshell.AppActivate(WScript.arguments(1))
      WScript.Sleep 1000
    Loop Until bWindowFound

      Wshell.appActivate WScript.arguments(1)
      Wshell.sendkeys "%n"       ' <= Keyboard short cut for Alt-n, you might need to change the n to your shortcut 
      WScript.Sleep 400
      Wshell.sendkeys WScript.arguments(0)
      Wshell.sendkeys "%s"      ' <= Keyboard short cut for Alt-s, you might need to change the n to your shortcut 
      WScript.Sleep 400
end if
```

Comment: Wscript need to be add on the reference? Which one the reference? :) Thank you so much for you good sample!

Comment: Hi storax, can you also help to to create the saveas.vbs , this is the full declaration? Im so sorry im new in the vbscripting :(

Comment: Wscript does not need to ab added to the reference. I have posted the content of the file saveas.vbs. The line `Shell "wscript " & SaveAs & xlFile & " Save as" ` just calls `wscript` on your system with the file `SaveAs` to run and the parameters `xlfile` (that is the file where the SAP download will be saved) and  `" Save As"`. That shoud match the title of the Windows Dialogbox which appears.

Comment: Hi Storax! I',m trying to execute the script but i receive this message from Windows Script Host: "There is no script engine for file extension '.xls' " You know how to solve this?

Comment: Extension for a vbs script needs to be VBS. If this does not help please create a new question with all the details what you tried, what is not working and what error messages you get