# Context Menu for SAP GUI export not appear when pressed with VBA

Tags: excel, vba, export, sap-gui

While running my VBA code it opens all the correct functions, but when it comes to utilizing the export function - the drop down menu isn't available when pressing export button with VBA, while the drop down menu appears when clicking export button with mouse.

[image: Export button example]

Since it's unable to select the context menu items - given the dropdown does not appear- it gives the following error:

> Run-time error '619': The control could not be found by id.

Is there a way to have the context menu appear for the export button ?

```
Sub SAPconn()

Shell "C:\Program Files (x86)\SAP\FrontEnd\SAPgui\saplogon.exe", 4
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Do Until WshShell.AppActivate("SAP Logon ")
    Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("0:00:01")
Loop 'keeps looping the wait time until SAP is successfully opened

Set WshShell = Nothing

   Set SapGuiAuto = GetObject("SAPGUI") 'open SAP 
   Set app = SapGuiAuto.GetScriptingEngine 'use the VBScripting ability in SAP
      Set connection = app.Openconnection("Production", True) 'open the specific SAP connection
         Set session = connection.Children(0) 

ThisWorkbook.Activate 'ensure we are getting the information from this specific workbook for the next portion of code

With session
.findById("wnd[0]/usr/txtRSYST-BNAME").Text = Range("c2").Formula 'username
.findById("wnd[0]/usr/pwdRSYST-BCODE").Text = Range("c3").Value 'password
.findById("wnd[0]/usr/txtRSYST-LANGU").Text = "EN" 'language

.findById("wnd[0]").maximize
.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0 'ENTER to log in 

end with
  
On Error GoTo 0
With session

.findById("wnd[0]").maximize
.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlIMAGE_CONTAINER/shellcont/shell/shellcont[0]/shell").expandNode "Root"
.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlIMAGE_CONTAINER/shellcont/shell/shellcont[0]/shell").expandNode "0000000007"
.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlIMAGE_CONTAINER/shellcont/shell/shellcont[0]/shell").expandNode "0000000039"
.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlIMAGE_CONTAINER/shellcont/shell/shellcont[0]/shell").expandNode "0000000040"
.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlIMAGE_CONTAINER/shellcont/shell/shellcont[0]/shell").selectedNode = "0000000041"
.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlIMAGE_CONTAINER/shellcont/shell/shellcont[0]/shell").topNode = "F00007"
.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlIMAGE_CONTAINER/shellcont/shell/shellcont[0]/shell").doubleClickNode "0000000041"
.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cmbP_ZINPST").key = "F"
.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cmbP_ZINPST").setFocus
.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[1]/btn[8]").press
.findById("wnd[0]").maximize

.findById("wnd[0]").maximize

.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlCONT1/shellcont/shell").PressToolbarContextButton ("&MB_EXPORT")
.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlCONT1/shellcont/shell").selectContextMenuItem "&XXL"
.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
End With
End Sub
```

Exampe of what code does is shown in this video: [video](https://clipchamp.com/watch/MH4AVJ0KNno)

I have enabled scripting in SAP GUI.
I have activated trust access to VBA project object model in the excel macros trust settings.

Comment: If people reproduce using the program `SALV_VERI002` which exists in all systems (maybe data is first to be generated via program `BCALV_GENERATE_ALV_T_T2`), if you record the export button you mention and you play the script, the methods `PressToolbarContextButton` and `selectContextMenuItem` of [`GuiGridView`](https://help.sap.com/docs/search?q=GuiGridView&product=sap_gui_for_windows) work as expected i.e. start a Windows dialog to select a file (NB: it may simplify your script to deselect the SAP GUI option "Show native Microsoft Windows dialogs").

Comment: At which line does the RTE occur? I guess it is either `findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlCONT1/shellcont/shell").PressToolbarContextButton ("&MB_EXPORT")` or `findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlCONT1/shellcont/shell").selectContextMenuItem "&XXL"`.  Is that right? Or is it on the second `.findById("wnd[0]").maximize`?

Comment: @Storax
`findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlCONT1/shellcont/shell").PressToolbarContextButton ("&MB_EXPORT")` is where is is supposed to open the context menu.

weirdly enough I got it to semi work by opening a dialog through application.
`Application.Dialogs(xlDialogOpen).Show("export")` after I close the dialog box for excel, the SAP code works perfectly - opens the context menu and selects XXL file type. 

I am not sure why-- and I am not sure how to make it work without an unrelated dialog box. Maybe I could set SAP as the application rather than excel and try the same method.

Comment: Maybe you need to change one setting in the [SAPGUI](https://blogs.sap.com/2014/03/26/new-scripting-option-in-sap-gui-for-windows-730-pl-8/). Otherwise you could also have a look at an IMO now obsolete [approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58779515/6600940)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you @storax for the help be determining that is might be a SAPGUI setting error which led me into looking into solutions for the toolbox selection.

- I found solution at https://simpleexcelvba.com/how-to-save-as-and-open-excel-during-sap-scripting/
  Ends out the VBA code was running faster than the SAP program. Adding a 3 second delay allowed time for the context menu to open prior to preceding to the next step, which caused the runtime error

  > "Run-time error '619': The control could not be found by id."

because the context menu item wasn't open in order to be found.

```
 with session
    .findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlCONT1/shellcont/shell").PressToolbarContextButton ("&MB_EXPORT")
    .findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlCONT1/shellcont/shell").selectContextMenuItem "&XXL"
    Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("0:00:03")
    .findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey
    end with
```

The wait time gave the SAP gui system the time required to open.

Answer (score 0):

You need to manually open the context menu

Try using

```
' session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlCONT1/shellcont/shell").contextMenu '
```

to open the context menu before trying to select the context menu item.

This should make it so the context menu appears

Comment: This didn't fix the problem - it is still not showing the context menu and is still giving the same error